# On click it should navigate users back with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Users are at this url: `http://devi/socialsites/test/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx`

When they are at that url there is a link text that should take the users back to:

```
http://devi/socialsites/
```

I have a javascript that is following:

```
function NavigateToRootSiteCollection() {

   window.location.assign(window.location.pathname);
}
```

But this just take the users to the same url. Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: Why would you think `window.location.pathname` would magically be `http://devi/socialsites/`?

Comment: Open your browsers' console, type in `window.location` and voila! Watch all it's parameters and corresponding values. Pick the one you need. If it's not there, use the full path and write a function that strips it down to `http://devi/socialsites/`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to remove but two first directories:

```
window.location = window.location.pathname.replace(/^(\/?[^\/]+\/[^\/]+).*/, '$1');
```

or only one, root directory

```
window.location = window.location.pathname.replace(/^(\/?[^\/]+).*/, '$1');
```